# sqlite3 python generate tables

Tags: python, sqlite, dynamically-generated

I am trying to generate tables based off the paramaters of a function. To generate the table I thought of passing a string of what I wanted to be executed as the following function:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('tutorial.db')

c = conn.cursor()

def create_table(name, unix, datestamp, keyword, value):

    command = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + name + "(" + unix + " REAL, " + datestamp + " TEXT, " + keyword + " TEXT, " + value + " REAL)"

    c.execute('CREATE TABLE' + command)
```

However when I run the command:

```
create_table('new','boy','girl','joy','joe')
```

I get error: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\David\Documents\learn_sql_\learn_sql.py", line 22, in 
    create_table('new','boy','girl','joy','joe')
  File "C:\Users\David\Documents\learn_sql_\learn_sql.py", line 12, in create_table
    c.execute('CREATE TABLE' + command)
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "TABLECREATE": syntax error

Thoughts?

Thanks

Comment: which version python are you using??

Comment: Replace temporarily your "c.execute" with "print" to see what you are sending to Sqlite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with this :

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('tutorial.db')

c = conn.cursor()

def create_table(name, unix, datestamp, keyword, value):

    #c.execute('CREATE TABLE' + command)
    cmd = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS %s(%s real,%s text,%s text,%s real)" % (name,unix,datestamp,keyword,value)
    print(cmd)
    c.execute(cmd)

create_table('new','boy','girl','joy','joe')
```